# Gatsby - Trying to Generate and Download a Text File

Tags: javascript, webpack, blob, gatsby

I've managed to create a function that generates a text file that the user can download.

It works perfectly when I run the development build of Gatsby, but when I build for production I get the error: **WebpackError: ReferenceError: Blob is not defined**

If I then try to add **import {Blob} from "buffer"** I get instead: **WebpackError: ReferenceError: window is not defined** and then it doesn't work with Gatsby develop anymore either.

From what I've managed to find out is that I'm not even supposed to use Blob with Node at all, and instead use Buffer, but I'm completely lost with that because it doesn't seem to replace Blob directly. Also, why does it work on my development build but not in production? Feels like I should be close to a solution?

Here is my function:

```
export function Download() {
  const data = new Blob(["Hello world"], {
    type: "text/plain;charset=utf-8",
  });
  const downloadLink = window.URL.createObjectURL(data);
  return downloadLink;
}

export default Download;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> From what I've managed to find out is that I'm not even supposed to
> use Blob with Node at all

That's partially true. You're right when you say that `Blob` is not using Node at all, however, when you run `gatsby build`, your code is parsed and bundled in a Node server, that's why it breaks the code. In other words, your code is interpreted by the Node server, where [there's no `window` or other global objects](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/debugging-html-builds/) (such as `document`) because they are not even defined yet. On the other hand, when you run `gatsby develop` your code is interpreted by the browser, where there's the `window` and other global objects exist.

You can easily bypass this by adding the following condition:

```
if(typeof window !== "undefined")
```

This will check if you are on the server or in the client.

Try using:

```
export function Download() {
  if(typeof window !== "undefined"){
    const data = new Blob(["Hello world"], {
      type: "text/plain;charset=utf-8",
    });
    const downloadLink = window.URL.createObjectURL(data);
    return downloadLink;
  }
}

export default Download;
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the simple solution, and for explaining it so elegantly!
This worked perfectly and now I also know why it didn't work before.